# Does faster RAM, in a slower system, produce lower than marked, CL timings?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, computer-building, workstation

I own a computer that has a maximum RAM speed of 2400MHz (DDR4)
Would a faster 2933MHz RAM module operate with lower CL timings because of the slower bus or would it maintain its marked timings?
If the CL timings are reduced, would they be less than those of the 2400MHz modules?

I'm attempting to determine the performance benefit, if any, of purchasing RAM that's faster than my system supports.

Comment: In my experience, more than 95% of the time, faster RAM does not provide any substantial benefit. I would not waste the money.

Comment: Putting tires rated 200 k/h on a  Citroën 2CV woin't make it faster; might even be *slower*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citro%C3%ABn_2CV

Comment: The speed of the processor is unrelated to the frequency of your memory especially the CL timings.

Comment: This might help: https://youtu.be/R7CO9v9rpOk?feature=shared&t=543

Comment: Thank you, @Mastaxx. I was unaware of that difference, in performance. I always purchase high enough capacity RAM modules that both sides are populated, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one real reason to buy RAM that is faster than your CPU supports and that is because it is cheaper than buying the specific speed you need.

CL (CAS Latency) does not go down to zero, buying faster RAM may mean your system *could* run at CL 16 instead of CL 18, it does not mean CL can go down to 8. It may well act like very slightly better RAM of a lower speed.

CL being lower *is* slightly better, lower latency is always good, but it is only one part of the whole chain of events of copying data from RAM. For the handful of seconds you may save over a month of using a computer it may be that there is no perceptible difference in CL16 or CL18 RAM.

Unless you are already at the bleeding edge of performance tuning there is no real difference and and I'd go back to my first point: the only real reason to buy RAM faster than your system supports is because it is cheaper or the same price as you will be getting higher quality parts at a better price.

That said, if you are mixing old RAM with new RAM then the new RAM will be limited by the speeds supported by the old RAM.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there any way to know what the CL timings would be before purchase and installation or is it specific to the brand and module?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to know without it fitted into a system. The specific profiles supported by memories can vary across batches as different chips get used and manufacturers will only list the main timing set they expect all modules to achieve. It's why people recommend getting matched modules from the same batch, because there are many subtle timings that can change across batches.

Comment: @KennyRedSocks but in general you should care less about CL and more about actual memory speeds. CL might get you 0.1% of a performance boost while going from 2000MT/s to 2400MT/s would be a 10% increase. CL is messing about in the weeds of performance. You might go from 15nS to 13.5nS latency with the difference in CL, but that timing only matters at the start of a data transfer, as modern memory transfers multiple bytes in a row and that delay gets lost in the noise. CL is not the main figure you should care about.

Comment: Unlike DDR4 that came before it DDR5 does show a significant performance improvement between the lower frequencies range and the higher frequency ranges. So you’ll unlikely to notice any performance difference between the the slower and higher frequency product line’s except at the extreme ends.

Comment: @KennyRedSocks from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency under the "memory timing examples" section showing DDR4 2400 the time to transfer the fist 64-bit "word" is for CL16 13.33nS, while the time to transfer the eighth word is only 16.25 nanoseconds so the cas latency gets hidden by the bulk transfer. The difference in CL timings is vaguely irrelevant for blocks of data.